# VS 2013 suddenly showing projects failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am getting below error suddenly for all projects. Any idea what could cause this issue. Everything was working till morning.

> The project file could not be loaded. The '`' character, hexadecimal value 0x60, cannot be included in a name. Line 1635, position 10.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Answer (score 0):

Resolved .. Somehow my vs 2013 target file at below got corrupted by some junk characters 
( C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets).

As mentioned in the error issue was at line number 1635 .